# Changing code from Java to C

Tags: java, c++, format, show

So I made this program in Java first and then I wanted to make the same program in C++. While in Java it worked perfectly here I have one major issue. I used a char variable for my array and in C++ it pastes the ascii  code I assume(smiley face,rhomb...). So this is a tic tac toe game so I want my program to display the numbers like this:
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 
and after I insert 1 to be like this:
X 2 3
4 5 6 
7 8 9
If I make the array Int I get instead of X and 88. If I make it char I can put the X and it displays it correct but numbers from 1-9 are rhomb etc. Help me please! Thank you.

```
    char A[9]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < 9; ++i, ++j)
    {
         if(j==3)
         {
             j = 0;
             cout<<"\n";
         }
         cout<<A[i]<<"  ";            
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
char A[9]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

should be:

```
char A[9]={'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
```

In the first version what you're doing is creating an array of characters with their ascii values (you can find an ascii table [here](http://www.asciitable.com/)).

Answer (score 1):

The overload of `operator<<` for a `char` by default prints a character, not the integer value stored. To get it to print an integer you can *cast* it:

```
std::cout << static_cast<int>(A[1]) << ' ';
```

Alternatively you could use `int` for the array.